# How to position horizontal scroll bar at center of DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was trying to position horizontal scroll bar at the center of that div. I tired with window.scrollTo() but this works for page scroll and not for div scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var outerContentWidth = $('.abc').width();
    var scrollPosition = outerContentWidth/2;
    $('.abc').scrollLeft(scrollPosition);

});
```

DEMO: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxkmkb0o/1/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following will give you your desired effect and scroll to the center of the div through a simple change in your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var outerContent = $('.abc');
    var innerContent = $('.abc > div');

    outerContent.scrollLeft((innerContent.width() - outerContent.width()) / 2);        
});
```

> This code will set the scroll bar to the center of the inner content.
>   But lets examine why. We know the minimum value for scrollLeft is
>   zero, and the maximum is inner.width() - outer.width(). So, half way
>   is easily half the maximum.

There is plenty more information on the subject [here](http://blog.briteskies.com/blog/jquery-set-scroll-bar-to-center-on-element).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cxkmkb0o/7/)

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but you can now use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for this, depending on the browsers that must be supported:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('center').scrollIntoView({ inline: 'center' });
});`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1nv2caw6/)

Comment: Thank you guys, It helps me in my angular project. 

``` setTabToCenter() {
    const actvieTab: any = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-tab-label-active');
    actvieTab[0].scrollIntoView({
      inline: 'center',
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scrollPosition = ($('#viewContainer').width()/2 + $('.abc').width())/2;
    $('.abc').scrollLeft(scrollPosition);

});
```

Comment: width of div having abc class is variable so its coming at center with different width.

Comment: @Jitu > and how are we supposed to guess that when you don't say it and your example has a fixed width ? What do you even mean by variable width ? And why wouldn't this solution which seems quite correct not be of help to you ?

Comment: @Laurent S its ok! As you said, I didn't knew that it was variable, but my code should've seen that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to scroll so that middle div is visible, just set `scrollPosition` like this:

```
var scrollPosition = $('.page').width()*2; // scroll by 2 pages, so third page is visible.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cxkmkb0o/3/

Otherwise if you want that middle page to be also centered within the view, you should add an offset to what I suggested.

EDIT: also you should notice that the pages in your fiddle don't have the same width as the "view". You should change the `width` of the page to `min-width` to be sure they take the correct width. Plus you should take into account borders when you position elements; each side border increases the width of the element.
[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxkmkb0o/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Might be usefull with some comments for better understanding, my approach:

```
function scrollMeTo($Parent, $Child) {

    let parentHalf = $Parent.width() / 2; // half of parent width
    let childHalf = $Child.width() / 2; //half of child width
    let childPos = $Child.position().left; // X pos of child (relative to screen)
    //We increase X with the center of the child (childHalf) - scrolling here we see the right half of the child;
    //We decrease X with the parentHalf to obtain perfect center;
    let scroll = childPos + childHalf - parentHalf; //how much we need to scroll to the element
    //We now add the needed scroll to the current scroll.
    let nextScroll = $Parent.scrollLeft() + scroll;
    $Parent.scrollLeft(nextScroll);
}
```

Or use as one linear:

```
function scrollMeTo($Parent,$Child){
       $Parent.scrollLeft($Parent.scrollLeft() + $Child.position().left + $Child.width() / 2 - $Parent.width() / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplay achive this by,

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#scroll').scrollIntoView({ inline: 'center' });
});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
    let outerContent = $('.abc');
    let innerContent = $('.abc > div');
    outerContent.scrollLeft((innerContent.width() - outerContent.width()) / 2);        
});
```