# Automatically center horizontal scrollbar of overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a div container that has `overflow: auto` set. It contains an image whose width I do not want resized even in smaller screens.

The code works fine but I want the horizontal scrollbar to be centered in the `div` so that the image is also horizontally centered. I tried adding `margin: auto` on the image but it doesn't help. The final output should be something like this where the horizontal scrollbar is automatically centered on screen resize:

[image: Horizontally centered scrollbar]

```css
div.content {
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/Test_rillke.jpg" />

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position horizontal scroll bar at center of DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747367/how-to-position-horizontal-scroll-bar-at-center-of-div)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the answers there all use jQuery. I would want the solution to be plain JavaScript.

Comment: Can get close, but not close enough...