# How to center click and drag scroll at the middle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following Wes Bos 30 Days JavaScript challenge and for Day 27: Click and Drag tutorial I'm wondering how to center the slider at the middle position rather than at the first (furthest left) position?

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return; // stop the fn from running
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item1">01</div>
  <!-- Scroll starts here -->
  <div class="item item2">02</div>
  <div class="item item3">03</div>
  <div class="item item4">04</div>
  <div class="item item5">05</div>
  <div class="item item6">06</div>
  <!-- I want to start here-->
  <div class="item item7">07</div>
  <div class="item item8">08</div>
  <div class="item item9">09</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
  <div class="item item11">11</div>
  <div class="item item12">12</div>
</div>
```

The code I've found that works the way I want to is the answer to [this SO ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747367/how-to-position-horizontal-scroll-bar-at-center-of-div), but when I implement it in Wes Bos' code, I am no longer able to click and drag at all.

Here's a visual example on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9EWifQ5xqA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
const startingEl = document.querySelector(".item6").scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this at the start of your script (after the `<script>` tag):

```
const startingEl = document.querySelector(".item.item6");
window.scrollTo(0, startingEl.offsetTop);
```

Comment: .scrollTo did not work for me, I found a solution using .scrollIntoView instead.