# Centering parent div scroll bar, having dynamic width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have one parent div and one child canvas, I want to center the scroll bar of parent div because I can't add any style to canvas in my project.

```css
#parent{
  width:80vw;
  height:200px;
  border:1px blue solid;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
#parent #child{
  width:70vw;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <canvas id="child">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

In this snippet, margins on canvas is for demo becuase the canvas has different width and height and it is centered.
I just want to scroll the parent div where the inner canvas become in center.
I have done this but no proper result

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var parent = $("#parent");
  var child = $("#child");
  var final = (child.width() - parent.width()) / 2;
  parent.scrollLeft(final);
  console.log(final)
});
```

```css
#parent{
  width:90vw;
  height:200px;
  border:1px blue solid;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
#parent #child{
  width:80vw;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <canvas id="child">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Reference to above code: [How to position horizontal scroll bar at center of DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747367/how-to-position-horizontal-scroll-bar-at-center-of-div)

If you want to check in live domain what am I doing:
https://mypagemaker.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your parental div in a taller parental div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var parent = $('#parent');
   var parent_sub = $('#parent > #parent_sub'); 
   var final = (parent_sub.width() - parent.width())/2;
   parent.scrollLeft(final);
   console.log(final);
});
```

```css
#parent {
    width:90vw;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    height:200px;
    border:1px blue solid;
}

#parent_sub {
    display: table;
}

#parent #child{
  width:80vw;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="parent_sub">
    <canvas id="child">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```